# How do I use multiple base classes for my CRUD operation in ASP.NET Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I designed an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application implementing dropdown list class and using the class as a base for Create, Read and Update classes.

Now I want to implement anonymous authentication and I have created another class for this which should ideally be the base class for the Create, Read and Update classes. When I tried to add it, the system says I cannot use 2 base classes.

How can I use multiple base classes in ASP.NET Core Razor (MVVM)

I tried using both classes but that triggered an error stating I cannot use more than one base class

My dropdown list base class

```
public class GLRefPageModel: PageModel
    {
        public SelectList GLRefNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateGLRefDropDownList(strMaterialsTransactContext _context, object selectedGLRef = null)
        {
            var GLRefsQuery = from d in _context.GLRef
                              select d;

            GLRefNameSL = new SelectList(GLRefsQuery.AsNoTracking(), "ID", "Description", selectedGLRef);

        }
    }
```

My Authentication base class

```
public class DI_BasePageModel : PageModel
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
        protected IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService { get; }
        protected UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; }

        public DI_BasePageModel(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) : base()
        {
            Context = context;
            UserManager = userManager;
            AuthorizationService = authorizationService;
        }
    }
```

My Edit Class

```
public class EditModel : GLRefPageModel
    {
        private readonly strMaterialsTransact.Models.strMaterialsTransactContext _context;

        public EditModel(strMaterialsTransact.Models.strMaterialsTransactContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public strMovement strMovement { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }



            if (strMovement == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //select the current GLRef
            PopulateGLRefDropDownList(_context, strMovement.GLRefID);
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var strMovementToUpdate = await _context.strMovement.FindAsync(id);

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<strMovement>(
                strMovementToUpdate,
                "strmovement", //prefix for form value
                s => s.ID, s => s.TransactionDate, s => s.QtyFromStore, s => s.IDPartNbr,
                s => s.QtyToStore, s => s.GLRefID, s => s.ShopOrder, s => s.TransactionReason, s => s.TransactionReason,
                s => s.OwnerID, s => s.TimeLastAccessed, s => s.Initials, s => s.LastUser))
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            //**Select GLRef if TryUpdateModelAsync fails
            PopulateGLRefDropDownList(_context, strMovementToUpdate.GLRefID);
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

I expect to me able to call the base class for my dropdown list operation in my Create, Update and Read operations and also be able to call (and use) the class for the anonymous authentication exercise

Comment: You can't. This is a language limitation. C# only supports single inheritance. You'll have to use a different strategy, such as composition.

Comment: I know that c# does not allow multiple class inheritance so that's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm trying to get tricks around this. I need a real seasoned c# developer as I am intermediate......

Comment: Composition or decoration. That's pretty much the main options.

Comment: Hi Chris, can you give me some examples? Bear in mind that I already have the 2 classes so if I need to do some tweaks your sample should point that out.

Comment: They are both *well* documented patterns. Do some research, and try something. If you run into issues/get stuck, then you can ask a *specific* question about that.

Comment: Well, if you could share some url that'll be great. I'm stuck as it were at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem by using composition design pattern all the classes into the DI_BasePageModel class as follows:

```
public class DI_BasePageModel : PageModel
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
        protected IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService { get; }
        protected UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; }

        public DI_BasePageModel(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) : base()
        {
            Context = context;
            UserManager = userManager;
            AuthorizationService = authorizationService;
        }


        public SelectList GLRefNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateGLRefDropDownList(ApplicationDbContext _context,     object selectedGLRef = null)
        {
            var GLRefsQuery = from d in _context.GLRef
                              select d;

            GLRefNameSL = new SelectList(GLRefsQuery.AsNoTracking(), "GLRefID", "Description", selectedGLRef);

        }
```

Thanks for pointing it out Chris Pratt